# Error: Returned error: unknown account - Web3 be the msg.sender of a functioncall to a Contract

Tags: web3js, contract-development, blockchain, msg.sender

i trying to call the function getRewards() from this contract:
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x4AB071C42C28c4858C4BAc171F06b13586b20F30#code

This function use msg.sender to give me the rewards to my accounts.
What i need to do that iam the message sender.

This is my code at the moment:

```
Web3 = require('web3')
const fs = require('fs');

const web3 = new Web3("https://polygon-rpc.com")
const contractAddress = "0x4AB071C42C28c4858C4BAc171F06b13586b20F30"
const contractJson = fs.readFileSync('./abi.json')
const abi = JSON.parse(contractJson)
const mSandMaticContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)

asyncCall()
async function asyncCall() {
    await mSandMaticContract.methods.getReward().send({ from: '0x560CC2be59c5deF53431783C3583B8f9F63b7793' })
}
```

Maybe this is allready correct but i get the error:

Error: Returned error: unknown account

Any idea how to solve it?

I think i need to add to from a account instead of my public key so i tried:

```
web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('PRIVATE_KEY');
```

but if i try to access the account with

```
var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
console.log(accounts[0])
```

or

```
console.log(await web3.eth.accounts[0])
```

i just get beck "undefined".

Answer (score 3):

The solution is, to sign the transaction before sending we can doing this with any method by this code:

```
encoded = mSandMaticContract.methods.getReward().encodeABI()
var block = await web3.eth.getBlock("latest");
var gasLimit = Math.round(block.gasLimit / block.transactions.length);

var tx = {
    gas: gasLimit,
    to: publicKey,
    data: encoded
}

web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey).then(signed => {
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction).on('receipt', console.log)
})
```

Comment: Public key is smart contract address or something else?

Comment: How to get the private in a dapp?

Answer (score 1):

you can add this line before sending transaction

```js
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(privateKey);
```